# Error when passing data to the next ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsstring, uistoryboard

I'm trying to pass data between ViewControllers. The data string is obtained from a `UIPickerView`. However, I'm getting an error. Firstly, here's where I'm populating the `UIPickerView`.

```
- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender
{
    NSDictionary *courseNames;
    if(![_txtBox.text isEqual:@""]) //if not empty
    {
        courseNames = [self retrieveCourseNamesForSemester:_txtBox.text];
        for (NSString *key in courseNames)
        {
            NSString *val = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",key,[courseNames objectForKey:key]];

            if([courseArray count]==0)
            {
                courseArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:val];
            }
            else
            {
                [courseArray addObject:val];
            }
        }
        [_coursePicker reloadAllComponents];
        _coursePicker.hidden=false;
    }

    [_txtBox resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Here is how I'm trying to pass the data to the second `ViewController` (`GradesViewController`):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    GradesViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
    @try
    {
        [controller setCourseToSearch:[NSString stringWithString:selectedCourse]];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ --- %@",exception, selectedCourse);
        if([selectedCourse isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {
            NSLog(@"it IS a string");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"it is NOT a string");
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here is where I'm setting `selectedCourse`:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    selectedCourse = [NSString stringWithString:[courseArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]];
}
```

and the property in `GradesViewController` is defined as follows:

```
@property (assign) NSString *courseToSearch;
```

The exception handling in `prepareForSegue` outputs the following:

```
2014-03-29 11:00:08.292 WebServiceTest[46154:60b] -[UIViewController setCourseToSearch:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe29ac60 --- 43-214: Course Name
2014-03-29 11:00:08.292 WebServiceTest[46154:60b] it IS a string
```

Why is it saying I've sent an "unrecognized selector" when I'm sending an NSString? Shouldn't the assignment `selectedCourse = [NSString stringWithString:[courseArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]];` make sure that it's an `NSString`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the string, it's with your storyboard because you haven't set the correct view controller class. This is why you get **UIViewController** in `-[UIViewController setCourseToSearch:]: unrecognised ...`

Correct the class name in the storyboard.

Then, change your string management so you aren't repeatedly creating new strings (i.e. remove `stringWithString:` usage) and change this property:

```
@property (assign) NSString *courseToSearch;
```

to

```
@property (strong) NSString *courseToSearch;
```

because you should be retaining (or copying) objects.

Comment: Wow. I completely overlooked that. Thanks!